# node js and xampp conflicts

Tags: node.js, apache, npm, xampp

I run an apache server on localhost using XAMPP and this will mostly work with no problems.

Ocassionaly when I run npm install on a project to install it's dependencies, my connection to the apache server is disrupted, I am unable to access any webpages, I cannot turn off my apache and my machine will not even shutdown and I have to hard reset.

Does anybody know what is happening here and how I can

a) get myself out the situation when it occurs

and

b) prevent it from occurring

I've tried to kill the node processes using pkill node with no success.

Once I hard reset the machine I no longer have any issue.

I believe my problem to be becuase of the fact that I run npm install from inside my htdocs folder which is where apache will usually run from so the obvious solution would be to not do that but does that mean that if an project folder I want o use runs with node that I cannot use xampp?

Comment: More details might be needed to resolve this. What packages cause these? Can you post `npm install...` output of a case when this occurs?

Comment: What OS are you running ? What node/npm version are you using? What xampp version ? Have you tried to run "npm install ..." outside the htdocs root and copy the files then over ?